# How can I hide id from url?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I hide the id from the URL but the same content display? Example:

```
https://example.com/index.html#about
```

To

```
https://example.com/index.html
```

But the content same displayed. How it could be possible? Because I saw this thing on many websites.

**Thanks In Advance**

Comment: You're looking for `.preventDefault`.

Comment: Yes, Now It Is Clear

Comment: Different websites use different architectures. In a traditional multi-page website, the url `example.com/index.html#about` points the browser at the element containing `id=about` on the `index.html` web page. But in a Single Page Application (SPA) which uses hashfragments as pseudo-page-signifiers, then the url `example.com/index.html#about` is the corresponding equivalent to a multi-page site's `example.com/about.html` page.

Comment: But till now also I have doubt in this. Can anyone explain it more briefly here? I already searched on google